# Making it unable to open MozillaFirefox with safe mode

Tags: 14.04, mozilla

Is there a possibility of preventing to run Mozilla Firefox in the safe mode?

I am using some plugins that ban acess to certain sites but my lil brother is smart enought to run mozilla in a safe mode and get on them.

How would you solve this problem if it was your lil brother ?

Comment: Do you require a password for logging on to your computer?  If so, it is possible to control specific apps for specific users.

Comment: It may be more robust to do filtering at the router level rather than in the browser.

Comment: I hope your little brother isn't smart enough to read the answer below...  ;-)  And if this answer helped, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

- Enter `about:config` into the Firefox location bar
- Search for the preference named `toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes`.
- Double-click it and change its value '-1'.

If you check [this](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/components/startup/nsAppStartup.cpp#975) you can take a look on:

```
 // check whether safe mode is necessary
855   int32_t maxResumedCrashes = -1;
856   rv = Preferences::GetInt(kPrefMaxResumedCrashes, &maxResumedCrashes);
857   NS_ENSURE_SUCCESS(rv, NS_OK);
858 
859   int32_t recentCrashes = 0;
860   Preferences::GetInt(kPrefRecentCrashes, &recentCrashes);
861   mIsSafeModeNecessary = (recentCrashes > maxResumedCrashes && maxResumedCrashes != -1);
```